# Алгоритм Диница поиска максимального потока

Tags: c++, графы

Здравствуйте,на emax я нашёл реализацию максимального потока на c++ с помощью матриц смежностей:http://e-maxx.ru/algo/dinic . Я использовал этот код для задачи,но он выдал неправильный ответ.В чём моя ошибка?

```
int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin); freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
        int a,b,cap;
        cin >> a >> b >> cap;
        c[a][b] = cap;
    }
    cin >> s >> t;
    cout << dinic;
    return 0;
}
```

Входные данные:

```
4  //количесво вершин 
4  //количетсво дуг
1 2 1  // a,b,c.Ребро из вершины a в вершину b с пропускной способностью c
2 3 2
1 4 2
4 3 1
1  //исток
3  //сток
```

Выходные данные:

```
2
```

Comment: А матрицу нулем заполнить не забыли?

Comment: Во-первых, вы, судя по всему, привели не в точности тот код, который у вас. `dinic` в оригинале - это функция, её нельзя вывести через `cout`, скорее всего, вы забыли написать скобки (`dinic()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибки в приведённом коде следующие:

1. Вы выводите `cout << dinic`, однако `dinic` — это не вызов функции, это указатель на функцию. К сожалению, `cout` себя с ними ведёт странно, и [всегда выводит единицу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2064722/767632), а не, собственно, адрес функции. Если компилировать со всеми включёнными предупреждениями (ключ `-Wall`, если используете GCC и `/Wall` в Visual C++), то компилятор может сообщить о том, что в этой строчке что-то не так. Для вызова функции в языке C++ необходимы скобки после имени — `dinic()`, тогда функция будет вызвана и возвращён результат.
2. Во-первых, вы вообще нигде не считываете число рёбер из входного файла, а считаете, что рёбер `n` — столько же, сколько и вершин, и описания рёбер идут сразу после числа вершин. Это не соответствуют формату примера, который вы привели: там число рёбер записано отдельно.
3. В программах на языке C++ элементы массивов (в том числе двумерных) обычно нумеруют с нуля. Этому же принципу соответствует реализация алгоритма Диница на e-maxx — вершины имеют номера с `0` по `n-1`. Вы же при считывании считаете, что вершины нумеруются с `1` по `n-1`, поэтому вершина с номером `n` алгоритмом не учитывается или учитывается криво.